# How to manually cancel a JPA or Hibernate transaction when using Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am working with JPA 2 Hibernate implementation and Spring MVC to manage transactions

I am using Generic DAO pattern to manage database operations

Currently, we have a transaction that is a single method, something like:

```
someDao.save (someObject)
```

It is a `@Transactional` method invoked from a JSF page.

The method save is inherited from Generic DAO, it persists to database many entities with cascade oneToMany relationships, but it has to execute some 1000s of insert statements in the database, so it takes a very long time.

I'd like to offer a way to the user to cancel the operation, but so far, I'm unable to do that, when I call the method save(), it cannot be canceled till all the inserts have been executed.

I tried to throw some exceptions, to rollback transaction from injected PersistenceContext, but it's useless, it just finishes with no error :(

Obviously, I cannot throw an exception from within the method, it's just a single call from my source. JPA PersistenceContext does everything

Is there a way to cancel the operation and force it to rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#cancelQuery()

HibernateSession provides an **cancelQuery**-Method, which can be used to cancel the current query.
Note: It can take some amount of time, before the query really terminates.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, altough I can think that if my system is used by multiple users I can end up killing someone else's transaction, am I wrong? thx

Comment: @Makhz the HibernatSession#cancelQuery method is per session, and sessions generally speaking are allocated per JTA transaction or per thread, so unless you have some other unusual configuration it will not kill someone else's transaction.

Answer (score 5):

Saving 1000 entities shouldn't take that long. Make sure you benefit from [JDBC batching](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Entity_Beans-Batch_Inserts.html):

1. You need to use an Entity identifier that's not IDENTITY. IDENTITY disabled batching. SEQUENCE and TABLE generators allow batching.
2. Set the following hibernate properties:

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
   <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
   <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
   <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="50"/>
   <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="520"/>
   ```
3. If you want to timeout the saving operation you need to annotate your service method with:

   - For Spring

     [@Transactional(timeout = 30)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#timeout--)
   - For Java EE

     [UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(30)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html#setTransactionTimeout%28int%29)

This way after 30s your saving transaction will timeout and an exception will be thrown, rolling back all your inserts.

---

### Batch processing

If you want to cancel the batch insert operation while allowing the already processed items to proceed, then you need to opt for batch processing.

You need to split all items into chunks and insert them in batches. For that I'd split the batch-start and batch-end boundaries from the actual batch processing thread. So while the batch-start and batch-end are triggered by a web request, the batch processing is run by a dedicated [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

This way you can:

- process batches concurrently
- stop all batch processing at once, using [shutdownNow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

Because the query executions are I/O blocking operations, you need to support Thread interruptions so when the batch-end thread interrupts the batch processing executors, you could be notified to stop processing the next batch and exit as soon as possible.

I'd use a separate ExecutionService

Comment: Thanks, well, I said some 1000s entities, not sure how many, but in the tests I have done it might be 25000 or so, and we expect much more, it depends on the data,  it takes some time to do so, also, I dont want to kill the transaction automatically, but manually, pressing a button cancel or something like that, but so far i'm unable to do that.

Comment: I updated my response with a batch processing design proposal.

Comment: And to avoid this Spring+Hibernate BUG, you will have to add 1 more second to your timeout, i.e., if you want 2 sec timout, set timeout=3:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9482